# vb.net change location of dynamically created object

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I am wondering is there an option to gain control any of dynamically created object, like `PictureBox`? What I am trying to achieve is to change location of one or more `PictureBox`. This is the code I am using:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim MyPictureBox() As PictureBox
    Dim i As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ReDim MyPictureBox(5)
        i = i + 1
        Try
            MyPictureBox(i) = New PictureBox()
            With MyPictureBox(i)
                .Name = "PictureBox_" + i.ToString
                .Visible = True
                .Image = My.Resources.test
                .Location = New Point(50 * i, 100)
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
                AddHandler .Click, AddressOf SelectPicture
            End With
            Controls.Add(MyPictureBox(i))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("You cannot create any more pictures")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub SelectPicture(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim PictureBoxName As String = sender.name
        If PictureBoxName.Contains("PictureBox_") Then
            Label1.Text = PictureBoxName.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim myPictureBox As PictureBox
            Try
                With myPictureBox
                    .Name = Label1.Text.ToString
                    .Location = New Point(PointToClient(MousePosition))
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am really stuck with this, and I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: In `Form1_MouseClick` you have no instance of `PictureBox` and you only declared a variable of type `PictureBox`. What's the scenario? How and which PictureBox do you want to change?

Comment: I want to select one or more PictureBox(es) then change the location by clicking somwhere on the form.

Comment: Or different words... as you can see, I can create up to 5 pictureBoxes, and my question is: "How to" move/remove/change image etc...  of any of that pictureBox, i have totally no idea how to do it. but after mouse click on one of them, the label1 change the text to the correct name (PictureBox_ID), but how can I "use" that "selected" pictureBox?

Comment: You don't need that array, your controls are in `Me.Controls` collection and you can find them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options to use. For example you can click the `PictureBox` and store it in a member field of your form.

```
Private SelectedPictureBox As PictureBox

Private Sub SelectPicture(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    SelectedPictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Label1.Text = SelectedPictureBox.Name
End Sub
```

Then if you want to move it:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    If (Not (SelectedPictureBox Is Nothing)) Then
        SelectedPictureBox.Location = e.Location
    End If
End Sub
```

Also you can find controls by name using [`Me.Controls.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim c As Control = Me.Controls.Find("YourControlName", True)
'Then you can cast the control to the type that you know
```

Comment: You are genius, I spend actually two weeks trying to do it, or find out how to do it Thank YOU so much. I have one more question, can I use "DirectCast" for multiple objects of the same type?

Comment: You are welcome :) direct cast converts only one object and you can call it multiple times to cast multiple objects.

Comment: What I exactly need this code for (that maybe will be more understandable :)) I want to make something like photo album, that can be printable. I simply don't see older people dragging around each picture separately, so for the "multi selection" i created a collision detection rectangle, and everything that touching this rectangle suppose to be selected and available to move around... Honestly I never ever create or use dynamically created objects. Can you, please tell me how can I change location for 2 or more pictureBox?

Comment: "the answer is usefull" I unlocked just now, because to use this feature I have to achieve level 15 or something like that.

Comment: Changing the location for 2 or more picturebox is the same as the way for one picturebox, you can have your selected pictureboxes in a `List<PictireBox>` or an array, then set the new location for them using a for loop. But the more important question is where do you want to move them all, do you want to set the location of all selected pictureboxes to clicked point? Then they will be stacked on each other.

Comment: oh, array list, I wasn't think this way, but it's much more simple than my thinking, and for the movement, I was thinking for something like this, selected pictureBox1,2,3...Location (if they go to negative position) then... Mouse.Location - PictureBox1.Location = X... then PictureBox2,3...location - X... and all PictureBox.Location will be stored in *.ini file (i found settings.dll that is easiest way [for me] to store settings). Once again, thank YOU so much, you are really life and time saver.